# Elite Dangerous: NPC Arch Enemies?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I play private/solo play sessions in Elite Dangerous with friends and was wondering if there were arch enemies in game?

I was randomly attacked by an NPC while docking - I was not wanted in that system and didn't have any illicit cargo. In the middle of docking an NPC named Jorggs blew me to pieces. I thought maybe it was a bug or something, but I've noticed now this same character follows me from system to system, interdicts whenever he can and tries to initiate combat. I've no clue who he is but it says mission target under his name when I scan him. I didn't have any active missions at the time so... I'm wondering if this is a new thing? Maybe I called his mom a spaceslut or something and now he's got it in for me?

Anyone else have a Jorggs of their own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes completing or failing a mission will generate an NPC that follows you around. The two types I can recall are a post-failure assassin and a post-success alternate mission messenger.

The messages they send should give you a clue what the NPC is about.

Comment: Recently, I bought a bunch of some commodity at a spaceport for an engineer, and was followed around by a dude half the night till I finally submitted and kicked his butt. He was very persistent, and would harass me, wake scanning and following me probably 50ly. 

Also if you switch powerplay powers, you'll get harassed for a few days by your old power. I have seen this prior to 2.0, but haven't done any power play stuff since 2.0.

Comment: In should update this. Since 2.1, there's also during-mission NPCs that can generate, often with a mission update warning about them.